# If there is a binary vector space S , which is contained in it's dual S⊥ , does this mean that every element of S must be self-orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coding-theory, dual-spaces

If there is a binary vector space $\bar{S}$, which is contained in it's dual $\bar{S}^{\perp}$, does this mean that every element of $S$ must be self-orthogonal?

---

Let me explain the specific case (taken from "Quantum Error Correction Via Codes Over GF(4)", Calderbank, Rains, Shor, Sloane):

$\bar{E}$ is a $2n$-dimensional binary vector space. Its elements are written $(a|b)$. It is equipped with the inner product $((a|b),(a'|b'))= a.b' + a'.b$ (note this is a symplectic inner product).

$\bar{S}$ is an $(n-k)$-dimensional linear subspace of $\bar{E}$ which is contained in its dual $\bar{S}^{\perp}$, with respect to the inner product defined above.

---

So my understanding is that every element of $\bar{S}$ must be self orthogonal in order to satisfy the above criteria?

Comment: Correct. It does follow that all the words of $S$ are self-orthogonal. In the binary world (as opposed to $GF(4)$) every even weight word is orthogonal to itself.